# Apply a layout to ActionBar menu item and make it clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, menuitem

I am trying to use icon fonts with ActionBar menu item using a custom layout. Applying a layout to the menu item does solve the problem and the icon font renders perfect but doing so make the menu item un-clickable. Is there a way to solve this?

I am trying to avoid using a custom action bar because I want to use font icons instead of images.

Here is my code so far:

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/action_bar_icons"
        android:text="@string/ic_sliders"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.hackerrank.projectx.SearchResultsActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filters"
        android:title="@string/action_filters"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onFilterClick"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_search_result_filter" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_toggle_view"
        android:title="@string/action_custom_view"
        />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it inside a fragment try this:

```
onCreateView()
  {
    setHasOptionMenu(true);
    ...`enter code here`
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can setOnClickListener on the actionLayout something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(mMenuResource, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.notfication);
    FrameLayout badgeLayout = (FrameLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    badgeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent not = new Intent(DrawerActivity.this,NotificationActivity.class);
            not.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(not);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search_results, menu);
    MenuItem filters = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filters);
    RelativeLayout filterLayout = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(filters);
    filterLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("ACTION_FILTER", "filter item was clicked");
        }
    });
    return true;
}